# opening a shell and interacting with its I/O in java

Tags: java, linux, process, terminal, processbuilder

I am trying to open a shell (xterm) and interact with it (write commands and read the shell's output)

Here is a sample of code which won't work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Process pr = new ProcessBuilder("xterm").start();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(pr.getOutputStream());
    pw.println("ls");
    pw.flush();
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream());
    System.out.println(in.read());
}
```

When I execute this program an "xterm" window opens and the "ls" command is not entered.
Only when I close the window I get a "-1" printed and nothing is read from the shell

**IMPORTANT-**

I know I can just use:
    Process pr = new ProcessBuilder("ls").start();

To get the output, but I need the "xterm" opened for other uses

Thanks a lot

Comment: The title is misleading. An xterm is a terminal application that runs a shell. It isn't a shell itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the standard input and output of the xterm process don't correspond to the actual shell that is visible in the terminal window. Rather than an xterm you may have more success running a shell process directly:

```
Process pr = new ProcessBuilder("sh").start();
```

Comment: I know this is years old but other people will see this. This solution does not work by itself. For what you want to work you need to add -i to make it interactive. I have been pounding my head against for an hour before I realized I should just check the docs for /bin/sh http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/ElvisDeFreitas/jn484) a full java main example of how to interact with `shell` on `java 8` (is really simple do that on java 4,5,6 whatever)

Example of output

```
$ javac Main.java
$ java Main
echo "hi"
hi
```

The code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        final List<String> commands = Arrays.asList("/bin/sh");
        final Process p = new ProcessBuilder(commands).start();

        // imprime erros
        new Thread(() -> {
            BufferedReader ir = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String line = null;
            try {
                while((line = ir.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.printf(line);
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {}
        }).start();

        // imprime saida
        new Thread(() -> {
            BufferedReader ir = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            try {
                while((line = ir.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.printf("%s\n", line);
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {}
        }).start();

        // imprime saida
        new Thread(() -> {
            int exitCode = 0;
            try {
                exitCode = p.waitFor();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.printf("Exited with code %d\n", exitCode);
        }).start();


        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final BufferedWriter bf = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
        final String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while(true){
            String c = sc.nextLine();
            bf.write(c);
            bf.newLine();
            bf.flush();
        }

    }

}
```